# The system cannot find the file specified error Lua

Tags: lua, sublimetext

I have a folder containing main.lua opened in Sublime Text, but when I try to compile it in the text editor, it gives me this error. I have no problem running the code in the game engine. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it in layman's terms? I am new to coding. Here is the full error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['lua', 'C:\\Users\\eshig\\Desktop\\pong-0\\main.lua']]
[dir: C:\Users\eshig\Desktop\pong-0]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sublime Text, but I don't see any error here. It looks like your code ran without any syntax errors, but your game engine needs to run it in order for it to do anything. For example, in Love2D, the Lua code is made up of callbacks, but doesn't execute anything itself.

Comment: @luther - The question edited to unhide the error message

Comment: @laaane - lua.exe should be correctly installed, its path should be added to PATH.  Where is your `lua.exe` located?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you so much, rather embarrassed to say I did not realize I had to download Lua until your comment. I have it working now.